# Spring: push transition matrix into .properties file

Tags: java, spring

I've got transition matrix, each coloumn and row index represented as string, and value as boolean. For example:

```
matrix["first_state"]["second_state"] = true;
matrix["first_state"]["second_state"] = false;
```

But java doesn't support arrays with string indexes. So I push my transition matrix into Map.

```
matrix.put(new Key("FirstOpenState", "ThirdGreenState"), false);
```

I've about 15 states and about 300 lines of code that describe transition matrix. I find it ugly.

***Question:***

what is the elegant way to push those value to spring .properties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A direct mapping is probably going to be ugly too. I'd just list the properties as

```
outgoingTransitions.s1=s2,s5
outgoingTransitions.s2=s4,s1
```

Then load those properties into a Properties object, iterate over the keys (s1), split the value (s2,s5) and populate the matrix map with the corresponding `Key` and boolean value.

Here's some quick and dirty code to demonstrate, using Guava for String manipulation.

```
import com.google.common.base.Splitter;
import com.google.common.collect.Maps;
import com.google.common.collect.Sets;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.Set;


@Component
public class Foo {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("transitionProperties")
    private Properties transitionProperties;

    private Map<String, Set<String>> transitions = Maps.newHashMap();

    @PostConstruct
    public void loadTransitions() {

        for (Map.Entry<Object, Object> transitionList : transitionProperties.entrySet()) {

            String sourceState = (String) transitionList.getValue();

            if (!transitions.containsKey(sourceState)) {
                transitions.put(sourceState, Sets.<String>newHashSet());
            }

            Set<String> destinationStates = transitions.get(sourceState);

            for (String destinationState : Splitter.on(',').split((String) transitionList.getValue())) {
                destinationStates.add(destinationState);
            }
        }

    }

    public boolean isTransitionAllowed(String sourceState, String destinationState) {

        Set<String> destinationStates = transitions.get(sourceState);

        return destinationStates != null && destinationStates.contains(destinationState);
    }
}
```

Comment: more details please. Or it will be better if you provide a little example which includes checking if transition from s2 to s3 is possible.

Comment: what is the simplest way to parse those properties to properties bean?

Comment: You can use the util namespace, e.g.
<util:properties id="transitionProperties" location="classpath:com/foo/transition.properties"/>

Comment: how to do that via annotations&